# Avrdude & micro clone

Tags: avrdude, arduino-pro-micro

I am trying to program a Pro Micro clone (black PCB, 5v), using this command

```
avrdude.exe -p atmega32u4 -c avr109 -U flash:w:pro_micro_ISP_B6_10.hex:i -P COM3
```

but this is the (obviously incorrect) output I get:

```
Connecting to programmer: .
Found programmer: Id = "╞ ("; type = b
    Software Version =  . ; Hardware Version =  .
avrdude.exe: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
```

It has never been flashed before. All three lights are illuminated when I plug it in. I am pretty sure COM3 is the right port.

What's going on here? Is my USB cable bad or something? I actually had this problem on two separate units, so I know the board itself is fine.

Comment: can you upload from Arduino IDE?

Comment: `I actually had this problem on two separate units, so I know the board itself is fine` ..... that conclusion makes no sense .... maybe you have two bad units